# Upload UWP bundle/bundle.msixupload file automatically using Terminal or Powershell script

Tags: powershell, xamarin, uwp, store

Whenever I build/publish  Xamarin UWP app it creates bundle(msixupload) file to upload Microsoft store. I can upload that file manually to the store. I am using TeamCity(TC) CI/CD to create bundle file so I would like to directly upload bundle file from TC using PowerShell(PS) script. Is there any way to upload bundle using Terminal/PS?

Comment: http://blog.krammesnet.com/2017/09/19/automating-publish-of-uwp-application-to-the-windows-store/

Comment: Thanks @Jason but it does not help me to solve me problem!

Comment: Looks like [the StoreBroker module](https://github.com/Microsoft/StoreBroker) (a PowerShell Module wrapper around the Microsoft Store Submission API) is what you're after